# Creating a Function or Public Sub

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am new to the community and to programming in general. I mainly have dabbled and used the web to brute force accomplish what I need. I am trying to clean up some code by consolidating like routines into a function (similar to the process detailed [here](http://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/ProcArguments.htm).) But I am at a loss how to begin. The code as written now is repeated over and over to insert different forms at the end of the document.

```
    Sub InsertQA17()

If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("\EndOfDoc") = True Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Select
        Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Selection.Range.InsertBreak (wdSectionBreakNextPage)
        Selection.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientPortrait
        Selection.Style.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
        Selection.Style.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
'OQE Form below needs to be changed to reflect the sub called
        Selection.InsertFile FileName:=OQEPath & _
        "\QA17.doc", Range:="", ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
        UpdateThisFormsFields

    Else
        MsgBox "Bookmark ""\EndOfDoc"" does not exist!"
    End If


End Sub
Sub InsertWELDRECORD()

If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("\EndOfDoc") = True Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Select
        Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Selection.Range.InsertBreak (wdSectionBreakNextPage)
        Selection.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
        Selection.Style.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
        Selection.Style.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
'OQE Form below needs to be changed to reflect the sub called
        Selection.InsertFile FileName:=OQEPath & _
        "\WELDRECORD.doc", Range:="", ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
        UpdateThisFormsFields

    Else
        MsgBox "Bookmark ""\EndOfDoc"" does not exist!"
    End If


End Sub
```

What I think I want to clean up the code is 
1. a Function that houses the meat of the code receiving variables passed to it when the ribbon button is pushed.
2. Based on the variables a Call to the Function that accomplishes the insertion at the end of the document.

The problems I see:
1. I have the code repeated over and over again for ~50 forms (the brute force method).
2. Some documents are portrait and some landscape. (I assume this can be a variable.)
3. While I understand the concept of a Function (I read the link several times), I don't know how to begin. I know it should be easy.

Again, I am learning so please be gentle. If you must send me in the right direction.

Thank you,
Randy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Here is the code you requested. There are two procedures. Note that the first one is Public because you might want to call it from the keyboard. The other one is Private because it will never be called except by the first one. Place both in a normal code module (by default "Module1").

```
Sub Call_InsertFile()

    Dim Done As Boolean
    Dim Ffn As String                   ' full file name (incl path)
    Dim Orient As WdOrientation

    Ffn = "D:\My Documents\STO 170112 Topo's Recipe.docx"
    Orient = wdOrientPortrait

    If Len(Dir(Ffn)) Then
        Done = InsertFile(Ffn, Orient)
        If Not Done Then
            MsgBox "Sorry, the insert failed.", vbCritical, "Document error"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "A file by the name of" & vbCr & _
               Ffn & vbCr & _
               "doesn't exist.", vbInformation, "Invalid file info"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function InsertFile(ByVal Ffn As String, _
                            ByVal Orient As WdOrientation) As Boolean
    ' 17 Mar 2017

    Dim Rng As Range

    With ActiveDocument
        If .Bookmarks.Exists("\EndOfDoc") Then
            Set Rng = .Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range
            ' this range has zero length: start and end are the same
            With Rng
                .PageSetup.Orientation = Orient
                With .Paragraphs(1)
                    .SpaceBefore = 0
                    .SpaceAfter = 0
                End With
                On Error Resume Next
                ' doesn't insert a page break if document is blank
                If .End > 0 Then .InsertBreak wdSectionBreakNextPage
                .InsertFile Ffn
                InsertFile = Not CBool(Err.Number)
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox "Bookmark ""\EndOfDoc"" does not exist!"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

The second procedure is largely what you already had. I changed it to use the Range object rather than the Selection object. You (almost) don't need to select anything in order to manipulate it. I made it into a function which returns True if everything was done as expect.

This procedure takes two arguments, File name and orientation. I think orientation is a logical error because there are a lot of problems, presumably, if you import a landscape file into a portrait document, or v.v. Therefore the orientation is decided by the receiving document and the argument will not be helpful at all. You should open the document to be inserted, look at its orientation and then decide what to do. But this was your idea.

I have added a few more niceties which you will find when you study the code. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. I am digesting the code now, to make sure that I fully understand it and learn something from it.

Comment: Why does the .paragraphs.spacebefore and .spaceafter not effect the incoming file, as it use to? My method removed the paragraph formatting from the incoming file. Is this a result of changing from selection to range? If so is there a means to retain this ability?